# Given subspaces $V$ and $W$ of vector space $U$, how do we denote the space of vectors that are in $U$ but not in $V+W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be a vector space and $V$ and $W$ two subspaces. It can be shown that $V+W$ is a subspace and that

$$\text{dim } (V+W)=\text{dim } V + \text{dim }W -\text{dim }(V \cap W)\tag{1}$$

I'd like to investigate the vectors that are in $U$ but are not in $V+W$.

The first thing I notice is that it doesn't seem useful to consider just "the vectors that are in $U$ but are not in $V+W$" because then we would be excluding the zero vector.

We must consider the (nonzero) vectors that are in $U$ but are not in $V+W$ plus the zero vector.

This set of vectors must be a subspace of $U$ because if $\text{dim } (V+W)=m$ and $(r_1,...,r_m)$ is a basis for $V+W$, then we can extend this basis to $(r_1,...,r_m, s_1, ..., s_n)$ a basis for $U$. Any vector not in $V+W$ can be written as a linear combination of $(s_1,...,s_n)$, and so this subspace has dimension $n$.

My question is how to denote this subspace?

I had thought of $U-(V+W)$, which I believe is using set notation (the minus sign used with sets) together with notation that I learned in linear algebra (the plus sign used with subspaces).

EDIT:

After thinking about the comment from Gribouillis, it is clear that what is stated above is incorrect. $V+W$ is a subspace of dimension $m$ and we can form a basis for this subspace with $m$ vectors; we can then add $n$ additional vectors to form a basis for $U$. However, a vector in $U$ that is not in $V+W$ is not necessarily a linear combination of the $n$ additional basis vectors. A vector $u\in U$ is a linear combination of all the basis vectors

$$u = \sum_{i=1}^m a_ir_i + \sum_{i=1}^n b_is_i\tag{2}$$

which means that $U$ is a direct sum of $V+W$ and the subspace spanned by $(s_1,...,s_n)$, let's call it S.

Any vector $u$ for which there is one nonzero $a_i$ and one nonzero $b_i$ in (2) is in neither $V+W$ nor in $S$.

So perhaps my new question is: is there a special notation to denote this subspace $S$?

Comment: A set difference of vector spaces is not a vector space, so $U\setminus (V + W)$ is not a vector space, even if you add $0$.

Comment: @Gribouillis is right. You say any vector not in $V + W$ can be written as a linear combination of $s_1, ..., s_n$. Clearly, $ r_1 + s_1 $ is not in $V + W$, but it cannot be written in terms of $s_1, ..., s_n$. The vectors $s_1, ..., s_n$ instead form what is called a "complement" subspace of $V + W$: https://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Complement_(linear_algebra).html#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20a%20complement,such%20spaces%20are%20mutually%20complementary.